# Why does blockchain.info API response with wrong balance value?

Tags: api, blockchain.info

Let's the [following address](https://blockchain.info/address/33WDB3nsVHH5qafCAriPb8Jmb1e3ptsY4h). Now the current total received balance is: `5,697.09329301 BTC`:

[image]

But [API](https://blockchain.info/address/33WDB3nsVHH5qafCAriPb8Jmb1e3ptsY4h?format=json) response is `569709329301`:

[image]

As you can see API response does't contain floating point therefore the total balance is very big.

Is it bug?

Comment: Aren't the two quantities equal but expressed in different units? 1 satoshi = 10^(-8) BTC

Comment: @Sven That should be an answer.

Comment: @Pieter Thought it wasn't insightful enough. Thank you

Comment: @Erik You have almost 4M USD?!

Comment: @ 4 Leave Cover not actually :))). Could you point me where the documentation describes that all values in satoshi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two quantities are equal but expressed in different units. 1 Satoshi = 10^(-8) BTC.